# Knucklehead trying redirection with mod_write regular expression

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a hell of a time getting this to cooperate. Basically I'm trying to redirect my site's feeds to Feedburner, but I don't want any feed URLs with parameters on them to redirect.

For example:

`mysite.com/feed/` should redirect to `http://feeds.feedburner.com/mysite`

But this URL should not redirect:

`mysite.com/feed/?post_type=custom`

Right now that second URL is getting redirected to `http://feeds.feedburner.com/mysite?post_type=custom` and that's problematic. I want that URL to remain untouched. Any URL that has a ? after the /feed/ should be left alone.

Here's my code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !FeedBurner    [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !FeedValidator [NC]
 RewriteRule ^feed/?([_0-9a-z-]+)?/?$ http://feeds.feedburner.com/mysite [R=302,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I played around with the RewriteRule but I couldn't get it to cooperate. I tried doing a Negative Lookahead for a question mark, but it didn't alter anything.

The reason `([_0-9a-z-]+)?` is used is because WordPress creates like [5 different feeds](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds#Finding_Your_Feed_URL).

Thanks in advance for any help. I feel like a dummy since I was heavy into regex a couple months ago and now I can't do it.

Comment: `/?([_0-9a-z-]+)?` should be rewritten to `(/[_0-9a-z-]+)?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question mark in a URL is not matched against in the RewriteRule, as this matches against the REQUEST_URI, not the QUERY_STRING. If you wish to not redirect if there is a query string you should be able to just add in a RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !FeedBurner    [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !FeedValidator [NC]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
 RewriteRule ^feed/?([_0-9a-z-]+)?/?$ http://feeds.feedburner.com/mysite [R=302,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Then it will only redirect if the query string is empty.

Comment: NB: I didn't really play around with your RewriteRule, it looks overly complex, and can almost certainly be simplified if this solution works.

Comment: Wow you sure made that seem simple. Haha. Works perfectly and thanks for the help! :)